# PHP difference when instantiating a new object?

Tags: php, class, object

I have seen in many websites showing examples of instantiating objects.

```
$obj = new foo;
```

which is straight forward, but I have also seen this:

```
$obj = new foo();
```

is there a difference? So far I noticed both do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, it is a matter of opinion. If `foo` had a constructor with parameters you would need to use `new foo($param);`

Comment: thanks a lot. thats all I wanted to make sure.

Comment: it says i need to wait 5 mins lol